# How do I create a slug in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, slug

I am trying to create a `SlugField` in Django.

I created this simple model:

```
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    s = models.SlugField()
```

I then do this:

```
>>> from mysite.books.models import Test
>>> t=Test(q="aa a a a", s="b b b b")
>>> t.s
'b b b b'
>>> t.save()
>>> t.s
'b b b b'
```

I was expecting `b-b-b-b`.

Answer (score 462):

You will need to use the [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) function.

```
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
>>> slugify("b b b b")
u'b-b-b-b'
>>>
```

You can call `slugify` automatically by overriding the `save` method:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    s = models.SlugField()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.s = slugify(self.q)
        super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Be aware that the above will cause your URL to change when the `q` field is edited, which [can cause broken links](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html). It may be preferable to generate the slug only once when you create a new object:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    s = models.SlugField()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.s = slugify(self.q)

        super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: shy have a special model type?  why not just slugify CharFields?

Comment: SlugFields set db_index=True by default, and also use a form field by default that has a validation regex to require valid slugs (if represented in a ModelForm or in the admin).  You can do those things manually with a CharField if you prefer, it just makes the intention of your code less clear.  Also, don't forget the prepopulate_fields ModelAdmin setting, if you want JS-based auto-prepopulate in the admin.

Comment: As Dingle said below in his answer, you'll need to replace `def save(self):` with `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` in order to avoid errors from being thrown when writing something like `test.objects.create(q="blah blah blah")`.

Comment: Beware that this code will update the slug each saves. your url will change, and "Cool URIs don't change" http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html

Comment: Why not make the slug optional and override `save()` to create slug automatically from title if current slug is empty? `if self.s == '': self.s = slugify(self.q)`

Comment: `slugify()` can also be found in `django.utils.text.slugify`, not clear when this was added.

Comment: @mrmagooey it's new in 1.5 ...in 1.4.5 the slugify method is still with the template filters

Comment: What if I have two Test objects with same "q" field?
I don't want to have same urls for two different things...

Comment: The `slugify` in django.utils.text can use `allow_unicode`, while the one in `django.template.defaultfilters` should be used in templates.

Answer (score 113):

There is corner case with some utf-8 characters

Example:

```
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
>>> slugify(u"test ąęśćółń")
u'test-aescon' # there is no "l"
```

This can be solved with [Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.9)

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
>>> slugify(unidecode(u"test ąęśćółń"))
u'test-aescoln'
```

Comment: utf-8 is now handled correctly by slugify (in django 1.8.5)

Comment: As @RickWestera said this is now handled by slugify, although if for some reason you don't want to use slugify, check iri_to_uri from django.utils.encoding: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/unicode/#taking-care-in-get-absolute-url

Answer (score 71):

A small correction to [Thepeer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837828/how-do-i-create-a-slug-in-django/843067#843067): To override `save()` function in model classes, better add arguments to it:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.s = slugify(self.q)

    super(test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Otherwise, `test.objects.create(q="blah blah blah")` will result in a `force_insert` error (unexpected argument).

Comment: One further very minor thing to add to thepeer's answer: I would make that last line `return super(test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.  
I think this method returns `None`, and I don't know of any plans to change that, but it does no harm to return what the superclass's method does in case it changes sometime in the future.

Comment: Please add that *from django.utils.text import slugify* is required for this solution.

Comment: @Routhinator did it

Comment: Putting out some feelers to ask if this is still a preferred method for doing this.

Answer (score 31):

If you're using the admin interface to add new items of your model, you can set up a `ModelAdmin` in your `admin.py` and utilize [`prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) to automate entering of a slug:

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}

admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

Here, when the user enters a value in the admin form for the `name` field, the `slug` will be automatically populated with the correct slugified `name`.

Comment: My `slug` and `name` fields have translations. How can I do that with translations? Because I've tried to add `'slug_en':('name_en',)` and got the error that attribute doesn't exist in my model.

Answer (score 22):

In most cases the slug should not change, so you really only want to calculate it on first save:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    s = models.SlugField(editable=False) # hide from admin

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.s = slugify(self.q)

        super(Test, self).save()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to set the slugfield to Not be editable, then I believe you'll want to set the Null and Blank properties to False.  Otherwise you'll get an error when trying to save in Admin.

So a modification to the above example would be::

```
class test(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    s = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True) # Allow blank submission in admin.

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.s = slugify(self.q)

        super(test, self).save()
```

Comment: Docs on [editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#editable)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) in your admin class:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: Could you explain?  How does the admin affect the project?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Django 1.7

Create a SlugField in your model like this:

```
slug = models.SlugField()
```

Then in `admin.py` define `prepopulated_fields`;

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

Comment: Excactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [docs for the `SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) to get to know more about it in more descriptive way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `slug` field with [SlugField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) and slugify a `name` field value with [slugify()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify), then save the slugified `name` field value as a `slug` field value in overridden [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) every time you add and change a `Product` object as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.utils.text import slugify

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And, you can prevent **broken links** by using `id` in addition to `slug` in the url as shown below:

```
                         # ↓ "slug" ↓
http://myshop.com/product/orange-juice/id
                                 # "id" ↑
```

So, the url takes `id` in addition to `slug` in `urls.py` as shown below:

```py
# "urls.py"

urlpatterns = [
    path(      # ↓ "slug" ↓　
        'product/<slug:slug>/<int:id>/', 
        views.get_product, # ↑ "id" ↑
        name="get_product"
    )
]
```

Then, you should treat only `id` not treating `slug` in `get_product()` in `views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

def get_product(request, id=None, slug=None):
    product_obj = None

    if id:
        product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    
    return HttpResponse(product_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases slugify isn't enough standalone. I'm using a different technique for slugs. I think this will cover most scenarios.

First create a slug.py file in your app directory and copy the following codes in it.

slug.py

```
import re
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


def unique_slugify(instance, value, slug_field_name='slug', queryset=None,
                   slug_separator='-'):
    """
    Calculates and stores a unique slug of ``value`` for an instance.
    ``slug_field_name`` should be a string matching the name of the field to
    store the slug in (and the field to check against for uniqueness).
    ``queryset`` usually doesn't need to be explicitly provided - it'll default
    to using the ``.all()`` queryset from the model's default manager.
    """
    slug_field = instance._meta.get_field(slug_field_name)

    slug = getattr(instance, slug_field.attname)
    slug_len = slug_field.max_length

    # Sort out the initial slug, limiting its length if necessary.
    slug = slugify(value)
    if slug_len:
        slug = slug[:slug_len]
    slug = _slug_strip(slug, slug_separator)
    original_slug = slug

    # Create the queryset if one wasn't explicitly provided and exclude the
    # current instance from the queryset.
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = instance.__class__._default_manager.all()
    if instance.pk:
        queryset = queryset.exclude(pk=instance.pk)

    # Find a unique slug. If one matches, at '-2' to the end and try again
    # (then '-3', etc).
    next = 2
    while not slug or queryset.filter(**{slug_field_name: slug}):
        slug = original_slug
        end = '%s%s' % (slug_separator, next)
        if slug_len and len(slug) + len(end) > slug_len:
            slug = slug[:slug_len-len(end)]
            slug = _slug_strip(slug, slug_separator)
        slug = '%s%s' % (slug, end)
        next += 1

    setattr(instance, slug_field.attname, slug)


def _slug_strip(value, separator='-'):
    """
    Cleans up a slug by removing slug separator characters that occur at the
    beginning or end of a slug.
    If an alternate separator is used, it will also replace any instances of
    the default '-' separator with the new separator.
    """
    separator = separator or ''
    if separator == '-' or not separator:
        re_sep = '-'
    else:
        re_sep = '(?:-|%s)' % re.escape(separator)
    # Remove multiple instances and if an alternate separator is provided,
    # replace the default '-' separator.
    if separator != re_sep:
        value = re.sub('%s+' % re_sep, separator, value)
    # Remove separator from the beginning and end of the slug.
    if separator:
        if separator != '-':
            re_sep = re.escape(separator)
        value = re.sub(r'^%s+|%s+$' % (re_sep, re_sep), '', value)
    return value
```

Then in your models.py import unique_slugify from that file. Then use it in save() method.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from yourapp.slug import unique_slugify # Change "yourapp" with your app name

class Test(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    s = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        slug = '%s' % (self.q)
        unique_slugify(self, slug)
        super(Test, self).save()
```