# Date translation in Django templates and URLconf

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I've a django website set in French in the settings file.

In my template, I've the following entry `<a href="/{{ year }}/{{ month|date:"b" }}/">{{ month|date:"F" }}</a>`.

In my URLconf, I have the entry `url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/$',MonthArchivePostView.as_view())`

The problem is that in the template, the date generated is in French (for example, for February, I've got `<a href="/2012/fév/">Février</a>`) but the url expects the English version (`/2012/feb/`).

I don't mind having the dates in the url in English or in French, I just need to have the same generated in with the template and expected in the URLconf file.

Thank you

---

Update quick-fix-not-really-a-solution : use the `m` format everywhere instead of `b` to have `/02/` instead of `/feb/`

So in the urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/$',
    MonthArchivePostView.as_view()
),
```

and in the generic views

```
class MonthArchivePostView(dates.MonthArchiveView):
    model = Post
    month_format = '%m'
    date_field = 'publish'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jkbr already said, unlocalize should do the job.

Beside of that, have you ever been thinking about adding a function  `'get_absolute_url(self)'` in the model definition of your entry model, instead of defining the url in the template?

It would be better to keep separated content definition (model) from content presentation (template).

Also it could help you in solve your problem.

Try adding a function similar to this one at the end of your entry model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from time import strftime
    return "%s%s" % (settings.SITE_URL,strftime("%Y/%b/",self.creation_date))
```

This should work (if I've understood it right, it's something about displaying data instead of parsing it, as explained in [Format localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#format-localization) section of Django documentation.

Then in your template you could do something like:

```
<a href="{{entry.get_absolute_url}}">{{ month|date:"F" }}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure how to do that. I use generic class (cf my update) so I don't really have a model for the month archive. I use the model Post where I have a function get_absolute_url like explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.permalink)

Comment: The generic class view [returns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.dates.YearArchiveView) only a DateQuerySet and the year, no models. I was using generic classes because it was supposed to be faster and easier but I'm not sure anymore. Also the get_absolute_url [must](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url) contain ascii char only, so `/2012/Feb/` and not `/2012/fév/`. Or maybe `/2012/f%C3%A9v/` but not that good...

Comment: It could be better if you use slugs for urls, and avoid non-ascii chars. Template tag [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) can be used also in model definitions importing `slugify` from `django.template.defaultfilters` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/837835/302076)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`unlocalize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#unlocalize) to avoid localization in the template.

Comment: How do you combine it with `month|date:"b"` ? `month|unlocalize|date:"b"` output an empty string and `month|date:"b"|unlocalize` has no effect (still in french)

Comment: Then maybe try this: `{% localize off %}{{ month|date:"b" }}{% endlocalize %}`

Comment: Strangely, the `{% localize off %}` as no effect, even on just `{{ month }}`. On the other hand, `{{ month|unlocalize }}` works (just not the right format). Maybe a bug

Comment: I just asked on irc, we can not chain filters like I did. The advice was to use custom tags or process it in the view.

Comment: Okay, I usually use `unlocalize` when I don't want have certains numbers localized so I assumed that it would work for dates as well. Good like with that.