# Django - how to in the form automatically generate slug?

Tags: django, django-forms

I generate forms by *CreateView*:

```
#urls.py
url(r'^add/$', ServerAdd.as_view(template_name="add.html")),

#views.py
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from servers.models import Server

class ServerAdd(CreateView):
model = Server
success_url = '/index/'
```

[models.py and add.html](http://pastebin.com/9S8p3VaL)
Everything works well, but in site I must enter *slug*. And now the question: how generate automatically slug like in admin panel?

I'm newbi so I please for step-by-step instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use this [django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/690/) to create a unique slug for each item. That way, if you have multiple items with the same name, it will increment like `item-1` and `item-2`. Save the code from the snippet in a file called `slug.py`. In your models.py, import the slug file. Then after you define your model class, over-ride the `save` method using `unique_slugify`:

```
from myapp.slug import unique_slugify

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
    ....

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        slug = '%s' % (self.name)
        unique_slugify(self, slug)
        super(Server, self).save()
```

This will create a slug based on the `name` field of your server model. To create a slug from a different field, pass in a different value to the `modulus (%)` operator(s).

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that the above answer will generate a new slug every time the instance is saved; this is bad practice for anything that will end up being shared (e.g. as part of a URI) since any bookmarked URIs will then be invalidated.

A more complete answer is [How do I create a slug in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837828/how-do-i-create-a-slug-in-django).