# custom django aministration view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using django administration view. I have a article model. Each article has a title, body, datetime, slug and a rating. By default, django make a form for creating a new article. 
I only want fields for title and body but django creates fields for everything. I wan't to hide the slug field. How can I hide or customize the admin new article view?

Here Is my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, max_length = 255)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    rating = 0

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
        exclude = ('rating')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article.views.article', args=[self.slug])
```

**UPDATE 7 MAY:**
I tried to specify the fields in my admin.py, to get it to work I had to remove prepopulated_fields for my slug. That lead to a post without a slug. Isn't there a way to get the title to a slug without a field for it?

Here is my original admin.py.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from article.models import Article
# Register your models here.

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # fields display on change list
    list_display = ['title', 'body']
    # fields to filter the change list with
    list_filter = ['created',]
    # fields to search in change list
    search_fields = ['title', 'body']
    # enable the date drill down on change list
    date_hierarchy = 'created'
    # prepopulate the slug from the title - big timesaver!
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: For your update, you could override `Article`'s save method to populate the slug based on the title, check out: [using slugify in save](http://stackoverflow.com/a/837835/3096768).

Comment: You should really move the Slug question to a new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the fields you want in [ModelAdmin.fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) or exclude the fields you don't want in [ModelAdmin.exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude).

For example, in a file called admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Article

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'body')
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your admin.py you should be able to exclude the fields you don't want:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('slug',)
admin.site.register(Author, ArticleAdmin)
```

You can also set the field to readonly in your models if you want it displayed but not editable:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, max_length = 255)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, readonly=True)
    rating = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the [`ModelAdmin` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude), to exclude fields from an Admin view, in your `ArticleAdmin` class you would specify the `fields` or `exclude` variable like so:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'body')

# or equivalently, using exclude:
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('slug', 'created', 'rating')
```

If you don't have ModelAdmin classes yet, refer to the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/) on [customizing the admin forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-form).