# How do I make the slugs work in django

Tags: django

I have followed the [basic polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/) and I have tried to modify it to make it work for slugs but it's not working. I went from this in my views.py

```
def detail(request, article_id):
    details = "blog/detail.html"
    context = {
        "article": get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    }
    return render(request, details, context)
```

and

```
url(r'^(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

to this in my views.py

```
def detail(request, slug):
    details = "blog/detail.html"
    context = {
        "article": get_object_or_404(Article, slug)
    }
    return render(request, details, context)
```

and

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Article


@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

but it's not working. How Do I get the slugs to show in my url

Comment: Post your Article model code, please.

Comment: the tutorial is the django tutorial on the site. part 3 where they demonstrate how to displayt the article id. but instead of the id I want to display the slug

Comment: @losee: I cannot find any model named `Article` in the tutorial

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: and I can't find any reference to any slug field either.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I modified it to fit my model which is named article. The model they are using is called question

Comment: OK, but please show us your code. As @Saturnix said, the `Question` in the tutorial does not support slugs. We can't guess what you have done

Comment: @AndreaCorbelliniI edited it. If you need more code let me know what else

Comment: **Tip:** add `unique=True` and `db_index=True` to your `SlugField` in order to make your models safe and fast.

Comment: @losee Using `slug` prepopulated from `title` means that no 2 articles should have the same title for urls to map uniquely to a single `Article` object.

Comment: @losee Checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837828/how-do-i-create-a-slug-in-django

Answer (score 5):

In your views, you need to pass `slug` argument.

```
def detail(request, slug):
    details = "blog/detail.html"
    context = {
        "article": get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug) # pass slug 
    }
    return render(request, details, context)
```

If you are creating `Articles` using admin, then the `slug` will get prepopulated using `title` field. But, if you want to create an `article` other than doing it in admin, you need to call [`slugify()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) function explicitly in your model's `save()` and assign it to the `article` object before saving it.

You can do something like:

```
class Article(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title) # set the slug explicitly
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # call Django's save()
```

**Note:** Since you are using `slug` instead of `id` for `detail` view, this means that no 2 articles should have the same `slug` i.e. the same `title`. Add `unique=True` constraint in your model for handling this.

Comment: I tried that. where is the documentation on how to use slugs in django

Comment: Check this doc link on `SlugField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the parameter name in `get_object_or_404`. Assuming that your `Article` model has a `SlugField` named `slug`:

```
get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
```

---

**EDIT**: User update the question providing the model. This part is no longer needed.

Since you didn't posted your `Article` model, I'm gonna provide an example of how you should code it to make it compatible with my example:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.db import models

class Article(models.model):
    #…
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.slug)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837835/1307020) answer. Notice how we override the save method to automatically generate the slug. **Might not be a good idea** depending on your architecture. I'd recommend to call `slugify` in a view or in a modelform like in [this](https://keyerror.com/blog/automatically-generating-unique-slugs-in-django) tutorial.

Comment: There are some inconsistencies: `reference_slug` vs `slug` vs `s`. Also, I think you wanted to write `slugify(self.title)` or something like that, instead of `slugify(self.slug)` (what's the point of making a slug out of a slug?)

Comment: @Saturnix  your code doesn't work. I've posted my model as well

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini: Very simple: SlugField doesn't automatically slugify your text. SlugField works exactly like a CharField.

Ioose: code has been updated considering your newly updated question.

Comment: @Saturnix this is the error I get using your answer Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<slug>[-\\m]+)/$']

Comment: the url I see in this error (`['blog/(?P<slug>[-\\m]+)/$']`) is different from the one I see in your urls.py