# get_object_or_404() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

Tags: python, django

## TypeError at /vegetables/

get_object_or_404() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category
from .models import Product

def allProductCategory(request,c_slug=None):
    c_page=None
    products=None
    if c_slug!=None:
        c_page=get_object_or_404(Category,slug=c_slug)
        products=Product.objects.all().filter(category=c_page,available=True)
    else:
        products=Product.objects.all().filter(available=True)
    return render(request, 'category.html',{'category':c_page,'products':products})
```

urls.py

```
app_name='ecommerceapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.allProductCategory,name='allProductCategory'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/',views.allProductCategory,name='products_by_category'),
]
```

Includes 2 tables-Category, Product
models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category',blank=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def __str__(self):
      return '{}'.format(self.name)
    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('ecommerceapp:products_by_category',args=[self.slug,])


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

Base.html is created. header.html, navbar.html, footer.html are included in base.html. Other than these three a block content and endblock is created in base.html.

category.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block metadescription %}
    {% if category %}
        {{ category.description|truncatewords:155 }}
    {% else %}
        Welcome to ZUPER Store where you can get everything.
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
    {% if category %}
        {{ category.name }} - ZUPER store
    {% else %}
        All that you need - ZUPER store
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if category %}
    <div>
        <div>
            <p><a href="{% url 'ecommerceapp:allProductCategory' %}">Our products</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div>
    {% if category %}
        <img src="{{category.image.url}}" alt="{{category.name}}">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h1>{{category.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{category.description}}</p>
    </div>
        {% else %}
    <div>
            <img src="{% static 'images/Banner.png' %}" alt="Our products" width="500px;" height="100px;">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h1>Our product collections</h1>
        <p>Dummy content</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div>
        <div>
            {% for product in products %}
        <div>
        <div>
            <a href=""><img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="{{product.name}}"></a>
            <div>
                <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
                <p>{{product.price}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'am getting this error when I click on the hyperlink vegetables and cotton dress.

Comment: share that template and models.py file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465366/10968621 check this

Comment: You could try using pk instead of slug.

Comment: Show your imports at the top of views.py, I suspect you're importing the wrong Category