# Django - Redirect uppercase urls to lowercase

Tags: django, url

In my Django apps, I have many urls including `/(?P<project_name>[_\w]+)/`.
The `project_name` is defined by users and it is an attribute of the `Project` model.

I've added a validator on the `project_name` to check if it's lowercase. 
So new names are all lowercase but some old names include uppercase characters.

I would like to change all the names stored to make them lowercase but at the same time, I don't want users to get an error when trying to access to one of the url with the old project name including uppercase characters.
As I have many urls and many views, I don't want to update each to manually `.lower()` the `project_name`.

Is there a way to redirect all urls including `/<project_NAME>/` to `/<project_name>/`?

Comment: Why do you make `project_name`s with uppercase in the first case? Normally one uses a [*slug*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/glossary/#term-slug) for that.

Comment: Well, it was a mistake... that I now want to correct.

Comment: I think it will probably be easier to just add `SlugField`s to your models. Especially since `DetailView`s and `UpdateView`s have support for slugs (they filter automatically on it). Furthermore a slug does not only is put in lowercase, it removes diacritics, and other characters that introduce percent encoding in URLs, so it will make urls more "clean".

Comment: Write a custom middleware to check the URL and do the redirection.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Could you please detail a little bit more how this could be done using a middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hacky way with decorators

You could create a decorator for all your views that use a `project_name`:

```
def project_lowercase(_func=None):
    def checkLowercase(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            request = args[0]
            project_name = args[1]
            if not project_name.islower():
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(your_url_name, kwargs{'project_name' = project_name.lower()))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return checkLowercase(_func)
```

Replace `your_url_name` with whatever you named your url route, then import the function and add the decorator above each view function:

```
@project_lowercase
def view_project(request, project_name):
    # ...
    return "Hello World!"
```

### Slugs would be better

Alternitively as suggested in the comments and a better solution you should use a `slug` to store urls for your projects, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837828/how-do-i-create-a-slug-in-django) to see how to add them to your models and generate slugs.

To move your existing data to use slugs or just to update project names you can create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) that will alter existing data in your database.

Comment: As I have many views, I wanted to avoid changing each of them. But using a decorator as you suggest is adding a minimal change to each so it's not so annoying!

Answer (score 0):

The first option I would suggest is to avoid regular expressions, switch to [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) for your `urlpatterns` and use [custom url converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) for your project names.

In case you want to keep using regular expressions, you could restrict your pattern to only accept lower case project names `/(?P<project_name>[_a-z0-9]+)/`. After that add url pattern, which is (effectively) the same as your current one `/(?P<project_name>\w+)/` (note missing `_` - `\w` already includes that) to match all project names, including the legacy ones, the view for that pattern would redirect to your first view with the lower case `project_name`.

Comment: `path` seems indeed a better solution ! The second option is the one I thought about but I want to avoid duplicating all the urls.