# How to save two values from options in Django?

Tags: python, django

Am trying to save dropdown in django without using django forms am directly getting the form values to views.

This is my view:

```
class WelcomeForm(ModelForm):
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = Welcome
        fields = [ 'message', 'courses']

try:
   courses = Course.objects.all()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    courses = None

form = WelcomeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = WelcomeForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
           _process = form.save(commit=False)
           _process.save()    
            messages.success(request, 'Welcome settings has been added successfully')

    context = {'courses': courses}
    return render(request, 'welcome/add_form.html', context)
```

And thus, using courses in my dropdown:

```
<select class="form-select" data-search="on"name="courses" multiple>
       <option></option>
       {% for data in courses %}
             <option value="{{data.name}}">{{data.name}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
</select>
```

From the above, i can save name of the course, but i also need slug of the course to make user clickable ! HOw to save two values from the selected options ?

Comment: What is `WelcomeForm` if it's not a Django form? Please share the code for `WelcomeForm`

Comment: have made updates, and its just form without course. I am manually dealing the course

Comment: Try overriding the `save()` of your model - see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/843067/13448841